src/deform_conv_cuda.cpp: No such file or directory
I am using python3.10.8, GTX-3080, Cuda Version 12.4,
Is there anyone know why I can't compile these 4 files into my project?
from setuptools import setup
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension

setup(

name='deform_conv',
ext_modules=[
    CUDAExtension('deform_conv_cuda', [
        'src/deform_conv_cuda.cpp',
        'src/deform_conv_cuda_kernel.cu',
    ]),
    CUDAExtension('deform_pool_cuda', [
        'src/deform_pool_cuda.cpp',
        'src/deform_pool_cuda_kernel.cu'
    ]),
],

cmdclass={'build_ext': BuildExtension})




Don’t post code and errors as images. They can’t be searched for and       are unfriendly to accessibility tools for the visually impaired
